# OpenCV Python on WSL 2 error: "(-217:Gpu API call) CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version"

Tags: opencv, wsl-2

I am trying to run [YOLO v4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection#Methods) on OpenCV 4.6 Python with [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) on [WSL 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) with [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa):

```python
import cv2 as cv
import time

Conf_threshold = 0.4
NMS_threshold = 0.4
COLORS = [(0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 0, 0),
          (255, 255, 0), (255, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255)]

class_name = []
with open('classes.txt', 'r') as f:
    class_name = [cname.strip() for cname in f.readlines()]
# print(class_name)
net = cv.dnn.readNet('yolov4-tiny.weights', 'yolov4-tiny.cfg')
net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16)

model = cv.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
model.setInputParams(size=(416, 416), scale=1/255, swapRB=True)


cap = cv.VideoCapture('output.avi')
starting_time = time.time()
frame_counter = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame_counter += 1
    if ret == False:
        break
    classes, scores, boxes = model.detect(frame, Conf_threshold, NMS_threshold)
...
```

I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): \
>
> File "yolov4.py", line 28, in  classes, scores, boxes = model.detect(frame, Conf_threshold, NMS_threshold) 
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0-dev) /home/tong/source/opencv/modules/dnn/src/cuda4dnn/csl/memory.hpp:54: error: (-217:Gpu API call) CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version in function 'ManagedPtr'

I have checked the Nvidia driver by using *nvidia-smi.exe*:

```
 NVIDIA-SMI 516.59       Driver Version: 516.59       CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:0D:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 24%   51C    P0    44W / 215W |   2711MiB /  8192MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A
```

As well as the CUDA instance installed by `dpkg -l | grep cuda-toolkit`:

```
ii  cuda-toolkit-11-6                        11.6.2-1                              amd64        CUDA Toolkit 11.6 meta-package
ii  cuda-toolkit-11-6-config-common          11.6.55-1                             all          Common config package for CUDA Toolkit 11.6.
ii  cuda-toolkit-11-7                        11.7.0-1                              amd64        CUDA Toolkit 11.7 meta-package
ii  cuda-toolkit-11-7-config-common          11.7.60-1                             all          Common config package for CUDA Toolkit 11.7.
ii  cuda-toolkit-11-config-common            11.7.60-1                             all          Common config package for CUDA Toolkit 11.
ii  cuda-toolkit-config-common               11.7.60-1                             all          Common config package for CUDA Toolkit.
```

OpenCV should be compiled by CUDA 11.7 according to file *[CMakeCache.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/CMake%20Cache.html)*:

```
// Version of CUDA as computed from nvcc.
CUDA_VERSION:STRING=11.7
```

The nvcc is also pointed to 11.7:

```
nvcc --version

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: is `cuda-toolkit` downloaded from Nvidia or is it a 3rd party package?  Went down this road once, and you are better off installing the stuff using the downloads from Nvidia's website.  They have installation guides, and you will see that CUDA compatibility is highly dependent on the OS/distribution/kernel, etc.  See what they say about WSL.  Better still, look into their container toolkit

Comment: @ekrall I install following [wsl-user-guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html)

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419674).

Comment: Remove cuda-toolkit-11-6, you already have 11.7. Better to have only one instance, and prevent smi and OpenCV from using different ones.

Comment: @Braiam I have removed the CUDA 11.6 but the error still exist

Comment: OT: Is your card compatible with the version that you're downloading? Since I seee P0 I assume it's not a general purpose one (I have downloaded different cuda versions for RTX 3070 and RTX A2000 as stated in the site, even if both are named cuda and both are RTX)

Comment: @Sgdva it is an RTX2080, it should be compatible since WSL do not need to install an additional driver except the Cuda toolkit. It is dependent on the host system.

Comment: @kusocodeing -  You should include that relevant information in the body of your question given the error you have received. Might also run “strace -f -e trace=file ./your_cuda_app” looming for open calls to libcuda.so*.  Additionally, knowing which version of windows your running might help further eliminate possible explanations